# FilePicker onerror function not getting called in Version 2 of Pick function

Tags: filepicker.io, filepicker

I switched to FilePicker V2, but the onError function when using the pick method is not getting called now. It works with Version 1. Can you please specify if this is a defect in Version 2 or whether the way to catch the error has been changed?

Answer (score 0):

We deployed a fix for this issue today. The onError callback should now fire  in modal mode for v2.

Comment: Thank You Andrew. Will switch back to V2, check and update here